# How to check whether a file is empty or not using C?

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a task to check whether a file is empty or not. 
I want to check the file before my program is running, if the file is not empty I want my program to read that file, but if the file is empty I want my program to skip the function.

here is my code but it doesn't work well:

```
void read_file() {
FILE *f;
f = fopen("contact.txt", "r");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
if (ftell(f) != 0) {
    while (!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%[^\;];%s\n", contact[n].name, contact[n].number);
        n++;
    }
}
fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` i.e.

```c
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
if (ftell(f) != 0) {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%[^\;];%s\n", contact[n].name, contact[n].number);
        n++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in an environment where it is available, you may find the `stat()` syscall helpful.
For example:

```
struct stat s;

if (stat("contact.txt", &s) == -1) { /* an error occurred, check errno */ }
else if (s.st_size == 0) { /* the file is empty */ }
else { /* the file is not empty */ }
```

[`stat manual page`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat)

Comment: I think `stat` is POSIX and not C.

Comment: Probably correct - but I think most OS have it or its moral equilivant

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - if windows

Comment: This doesn't help much if you want to write portable code, and if you don't have access to the file name this also becomes quite complicated.

Comment: Lets face facts - either windows or unix. Use of the preprocessor come in handy here

Comment: Has nothing to do with "facts". There is no reason do that if a portable version of it exist that doesn't require prior knowledge.

Comment: If the portable version is inefficient is that still ok? Or if the software does not need to be "portable". Is being "portable" a bit of a restriction?

Comment: And if the "file" that is opened is non-seekable?

Comment: @JohnHascall, then `stat` has not much chances either, hasn't it?

Comment: @JensGustedt with `stat` you can find out what kind of object it is at least, also re: your earlier comment, if you don't have the filename, you can use `fstat()` on the file descriptor (again assuming a reasonably POSIX environment).  There are times when maximal portability is very important and there are times when reasonable assumptions about the hosted environment is just as reasonable.

Comment: @JohnHascall, these assumptions about the platform are just speculation. The OP said nothing about it.